# Node JS remove a specific object from array (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array of objects - lists[]; and an object - obj;

This is the lists array:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840c5ce237f22a1c7a1ac7"),
  name: 'list1',
  content: [ 'aaaa' ],
  description: 'aa',
  tags: [],
  lastmodified: 1,
  __v: 0
},{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"),
  name: 'list',
  content: [ 'list!' ],
  description: 'test',
  tags: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

and this is the obj object:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"),
  name: 'list',
  content: [ 'list!' ],
  description: 'test',
  tags: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

Simple Question: How do I delete the object from "lists", similar to the "obj" one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Object from array using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588709/how-to-remove-object-from-array-using-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the JavaScript [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to exclude the target object from the list:

```
const list = [{
_id: new ObjectId("61840c5ce237f22a1c7a1ac7"),
  name: 'list1',
  content: [ 'aaaa' ],
  description: 'aa',
  tags: [],
  lastmodified: 1,
  __v: 0
},{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"),
  name: 'list',
  content: [ 'list!' ],
  description: 'test',
  tags: [],
  __v: 0
}];

const targetObj = {
  _id: new ObjectId("61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"),
  name: 'list',
  content: [ 'list!' ],
  description: 'test',
  tags: [],
  __v: 0
};

const filteredList = list.filter((element) => element._id !== targetObj._id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use some sort of filtering... heres an idea.

```py
items = [{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840c5ce237f22a1c7a1ac7"),
  name: 'list1',
  content: [ 'aaaa' ],
  description: 'aa',
  tags: [],
  lastmodified: 1,
  __v: 0
},{
  _id: new ObjectId("61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"),
  name: 'list',
  content: [ 'list!' ],
  description: 'test',
  tags: [],
  __v: 0
}]

removeID = "61840def80a88d1b2ffce400"

items = [item for item in items if item['id'] != removeID]
```