# Different ways to remove Object from array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Title. I noticed that there are two (maybe more) ways to remove a specific object from an array in a document. Example schema:

```
var diveSchema = new Schema({
//irrelevant fields
    divers: [{
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
        meetingLocation: { type: String, enum: ['carpool', 'onSite'], required: true },
        dives: Number,
        exercise: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise' },
    }]
});
```

For example, [here they used $pull syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40588927/13062745)

```
Dive.update({ _id: diveId }, { "$pull": { "divers": { "user": userIdToRemove } }}, { safe: true, multi:true }, function(err, obj) {
    //do something smart
});
```

to remove a matching object. But sometimes, this is used

```
let dive = await Dive.findById(diveId)
dive.drivers = dive.drivers.filter(driver => driver.user.toString() !=== userIdToRemove);
await dive.save();
```

Which one is better and recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one seems to be better, because there is one db access, the second one has two db access (one for findById and one for save)